# How to run and compile C++ GLFW code using Atom with the package gpp-compiler

Tags: c++, mingw, atom-editor, glfw

So I want to use Atom as my IDE in my journey in learning GLFW. This is my code

```
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glEnd();

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

So i've already tried searching for questions similar to mine but to my luck the answers in those questions did not work. I already added the lib files of GLFW to MinGW lib folder and it did not work this is the error I'am getting.  I know that I am getting this error because the gpp-compiler can't find the GLFW lib files.

Thank you answering :D

```
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `_imp__glClear@4'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `_imp__glBegin@4'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xcb): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex2f@8'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex2f@8'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x101): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex2f@8'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnd@0'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4lMOFw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

So I've got it working so what I was doing was just compiling the program without it linking the GLFW libraries. Because I was using MinGW as my C++ compiler in atom I needed to add this to the gpp-compiler packages settings C++ Compiler Options -lglfw3dll -lopengl32 and put the glfw3.dll file in the same folder as your main.cpp file then it worked. Take note you have to put the lib files of GLFW to the MinGW libs folder and to add the GLFW header files to the include folder of MinGW